# react SyntaxError: Inline Babel script: Unterminated JSX contents

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am learning react and try to use hook. What the code does is getting data from Ajax and then display the list. However I got the error:

```
SyntaxError: Inline Babel script: Unterminated JSX contents (53:21)
51 | 
52 |   ReactDOM.render(
> 53 |     <MyList/>,
     |         ^
54 |     document.getElementById('example')
55 |   );
56 |      when I load the index.html in browser.
```

Here is the code in index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="react.js"></script>
    <script src="react-dom.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="babel.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="example"></div>
    <script type="text/babel">
  class MyList extends React.Component {
    constructor(...args) {
      super(...args);
      this.state = {
        loading: true,
        error: null,
        data: null
      };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
      const url = 'https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=javascript&sort=stars';
      $.getJSON(url)
       .done(
        (value) => this.setState({
          loading: false,
          data: value
        })
      ).fail(
        (jqXHR, textStatus) => this.setState({
          loading: false,
          error: jqXHR.status
        })
      );
    }

    render() {
      if (this.state.loading) {
        return <span>Loading...</span>;
      } else if (this.state.error !== null) {
        return <span>Error: {this.state.error}</span>;
      } else {
        var projects = this.state.data.items;
        var results=[];
        projects.forEach(p => {
          var item=<li>{p.name}<li>;
          results.push(item);
        });
        return (
          <div>
            <ul>the result list is {results}</ul>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
  };

  ReactDOM.render(
    <MyList/>,
    document.getElementById('example')
  );
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

If Ajex call get data, save it to this.state.data and then try to iterate it through it to display all its elements. 
Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put this in codepen and noticed on line 36 you weren't closing your `<li>` tag. I get that syntax error resolved by just closing that `<li>` tag like such `</li>`. Check out the codepen: http://codepen.io/justdan/pen/RpOWBz?editors=1010

```
var item=<li>{p.name}<li>;
```

Try changing to

```
var item=<li>{p.name}</li>;
```

Comment: You're welcome and hey, stuff happens =) Any chance you can give my an accepted answer mark?

Answer (score 0):

Do `ReactDOM.render( MyList(),document.getElementById('example'));`